# Svg image issue

Tags: svg

I'm trying to save this svg code as an image and I'm using notpad for that. But when i'm trying it showing issue like "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." How can I solve it?

```html
<svg height="18px" width="19px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 19 18">
<defs></defs>
<g id="Good-One" fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-width="1">
<g id="Footer_06" fill="#9EA0A6" transform="translate(-1141.000000, -3946.000000)">
<g id="Group-7" transform="translate(0.000000, 3204.000000)">
<g id="Group-6" transform="translate(75.000000, 733.000000)">
<g id="dribbble" transform="translate(976.000000, 9.000000)">
<path id="Shape" d="M103.121936,14.778 C102.743936,13.05 102.293936,11.457 101.843936,10.053 C102.293936,9.99 102.743936,9.954 103.265936,9.954 L103.283936,9.954 C104.120936,9.954 105.038936,10.062 106.037936,10.287 C105.695936,12.15 104.615936,13.743 103.121936,14.778 Z M99.1439356,16.02 C97.5779356,16.02 96.1379356,15.507 94.9679356,14.634 C95.2199356,14.229 95.7509356,13.446 96.6059356,12.636 C97.4699356,11.799 98.6939356,10.935 100.250936,10.422 C100.781936,11.925 101.267936,13.635 101.636936,15.561 C100.862936,15.858 100.043936,16.02 99.1439356,16.02 Z M92.1239356,9 C92.1239356,8.964 92.1239356,8.937 92.1239356,8.901 C92.3219356,8.91 92.5829356,8.91 92.8889356,8.91 L92.8979356,8.91 C94.3019356,8.901 96.7679356,8.784 99.2699356,8.001 C99.4049356,8.298 99.5399356,8.604 99.6749356,8.928 C98.0009356,9.486 96.6869356,10.377 95.7149356,11.25 C94.7879356,12.114 94.1489356,12.951 93.7799356,13.5 C92.7539356,12.294 92.1239356,10.719 92.1239356,9 Z M96.0389356,2.7 C96.5339356,3.285 97.5059356,4.554 98.5499356,6.525 C96.4439356,7.164 94.2929356,7.308 93.0059356,7.308 C92.9699356,7.308 92.9339356,7.308 92.8979356,7.308 L92.8889356,7.308 C92.6729356,7.308 92.4839356,7.308 92.3309356,7.299 C92.8439356,5.283 94.1939356,3.6 96.0389356,2.7 Z M99.1439356,1.98 C100.799936,1.98 102.320936,2.556 103.517936,3.519 C102.599936,4.626 101.393936,5.4 100.070936,5.985 C99.1439356,4.203 98.2439356,2.925 97.6499356,2.142 C98.1359356,2.043 98.6309356,1.98 99.1439356,1.98 Z M104.660936,4.662 C105.533936,5.778 106.082936,7.164 106.154936,8.667 C105.137936,8.451 104.183936,8.352 103.283936,8.352 L103.274936,8.352 C102.554936,8.352 101.879936,8.415 101.240936,8.523 C101.087936,8.145 100.943936,7.785 100.772936,7.434 C102.194936,6.813 103.553936,5.922 104.660936,4.662 Z M99.1439356,3.99680289e-16 C94.1733728,-1.59872116e-15 90.1439356,4.02943725 90.1439356,9 C90.1439356,11.3869484 91.0921471,13.6761336 92.7799746,15.363961 C94.467802,17.0517884 96.7569872,18 99.1439356,18 C101.530884,18 103.820069,17.0517884 105.507897,15.363961 C107.195724,13.6761336 108.143936,11.3869484 108.143936,9 C108.143936,6.61305159 107.195724,4.32386638 105.507897,2.63603897 C103.820069,0.948211563 101.530884,1.99840144e-16 99.1439356,3.99680289e-16 Z"></path>
</g>
</g>
</g>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: missing namespace attributes e.g. `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`

Comment: Your browser can't tell that it is an SVG image. It just thinks it is a generic XML file.  At the very least, you need to add the SVG namespace attribute `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` as Robert says.  You don't need the other `xlink` one for this particular file. But you may need it for other files, depending on their contents.